# Network Attached Storage: Pi not visible on home network

Tags: networking, samba

I am trying to set up my Raspberry Pi as a Network Attached Storage Device. I have successfully installed Samba but am not able to see my Pi from my Windows 10 device on the same network.

I am new to the Raspberry Pi, to Linux systems, and to home networking. I have followed these tutorials ([link 1](https://medium.com/@aallan/adding-an-external-disk-to-a-raspberry-pi-and-sharing-it-over-the-network-5b321efce86a), [link 2](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/samba-file-server/)). I am running “Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (Stretch)” on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ and have installed the latest version of Samba, as of 16th July. This was installed using:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install samba samba-common-bin
```

I have created a dummy folder to share (once this is working I will instead access an external harddrive) using:

```
$ sudo mkdir -m 1777 /share
```

I then edited the Samba config file

```
$ sudo leafpad /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Below are some lines from the config file. Everything below [share] I have added. Everything above was already in the config file (I have not included all of the file, only some of the lines that might be relevant):

---

```
#======================= Global Settings =======================
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP

############ Misc ############
   usershare allow guests = yes

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no

   read only = yes

   create mask = 0700

   directory mask = 0700

   valid users = %S

[share]
Comment = Shared Folder
Path = /share
Browseable = yes
Writeable = yes
only guest = no
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
public = yes
Guest ok = yes
```

---

I then saved, closed, checked syntax, and restarted Samba:

```
$ testparm /etc/samba/smb.conf
$ sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart
```

I believe this should now make the Pi visible on the Workgroup named WORKGROUP, as set in the config file. However, when looking on the network from my Windows 10 machine I am not able to see the Raspberry Pi (From Windows Explorer / Network the Raspberry Pi is not visible under "Computers").

The Raspberry pi is connected to my router via ethernet cable, and my Windows 10 machine is on the wifi (same router), which it recognizes as a private network (I believe this should make the Windows machine discoverable), and on the workgroup named WORKGROUP. I am able to access the Pi from my Windows 10 machine via VNC, again confirming they are on the same network. I have rebooted both the Pi and the Windows 10 machine, and am still not able to see the Pi on the network from my Windows 10 machine.
Is anyone able to help me make my Pi directories visible on a home network?

Comment: I made a comment about iSCSI a few minutes ago but it kind of makes no sense. iSCSI makes available a (virtual) block device that a single device could use, basically, whereas smb will share a "mounted file system" that a lot of nodes could then share.

Comment: Have you looked at one of these solutions? [samba share not showing](https://www.google.com/search?q=samba+share+not+showing)